# Which users are allowed to log in via SSH by default?

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, users, login

1. When I set up my Debian 6, I was wondering, which users apart from root whose password I know can log into my system via SSH?
2. When I install Apache 2 a user called www-data gets created. Does this user have the right to log into my system via SSH? But if there was some default password for www-data everyone could log in, seems unlikely to me.
3. Where do I have a list which users are allowed to log into my system via SSH? Can't find anything in the ssh config files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Paradeepchhetri isn't exactly correct.

Debian's unmodified `sshd_config` has the following:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
UsePAM yes
```

Thus, login via ssh would only work for users that have a populated password field in `/etc/shadow` or an ssh key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Note that the default value for `PubkeyAuthentication` is `yes` and for `PermitEmptyPasswords` is `no`, so even if you remove them the behavior will be the same.

In the question example, `www-data` by default won't be allowed to log in since Debian's installer neither assigns a password nor creates a key for `www-data`.

`pam_access`, `AllowUsers` and `AllowGroups` in `sshd_config` can be used for finer control if that's needed. In Debian it's strongly encouraged to `UsePAM`.

Answer (score 11):

By default, login is allowed for all users on Debian.

You can change it by allowing certain users that can log into by editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

As mentioned in the man page of sshd_config.

> `AllowUsers`
>
> This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by
>   spaces. If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of 
>   the patterns. Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID is not
>   recognized.  By default, login is allowed for all users. If the pattern 
>   takes the form `USER@HOST` then `USER` and `HOST` are separately checked, 
>   restricting logins to particular users from particular hosts. The allow/deny 
>   directives are processed in the following order: `DenyUsers`, `AllowUsers`, 
>   `DenyGroup`, and finally `AllowGroups`.

Comment: I added "on Debian" in case someone comes along and reads the question title and answer without reading the question itself. The general answer to the question title is, "it depends on the contents of the shipped `sshd_config` file." Some OSes ship with root login over SSH disallowed, for example.

Comment: Thanks, but obviously by default only root can login since he's the only one with a password in /etc/shadow.

Answer (score 7):

By default, `SSH server` isn't even installed.  You would have to install the `openssh-server` package before anybody could SSH in.

After that, any user has to pass two checks:

- SSH authentication
- PAM account checks

SSH authentication means that either the user must have a valid password in `/etc/shadow` or they have a valid SSH public key with the right permissions in the target user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Valid passwords are described further in the `crypt(3)` man page, but basically if the user's 2nd field in `/etc/shadow` is anything starting with `$NUMBER$`, it's probably valid, and if it's `*` or `!`, it's invalid.

PAM account checks basically means that the account is not expired.  You can check that using `chage -l USERNAME`.

So to answer your questions, to my knowledge:

1. Only root and the account you create during the installation wizard can log in on a new system
2. No, because `www-data` has a hashed password of `*` and there is no `~www-data/.ssh/authorized_keys` file
3. There's no single list, because there are multiple requirements, but to get an idea, you could try running `grep -v '^[^:]*:[!*]:' /etc/shadow`

Comment: Be careful, the empty password ***is*** a valid password, but as *bahamat* pointed out, the default SSH configuration (and default Debian configuration) disallow SSH login for empty password accounts.